# Send variable to another class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send variable **id**  from one class to another, 
for some reason I get error -> *An Object reference is required*.

The string that is returning the error

```
 public string RegApplicantInfo1 { get; } = $"/v1/consumer/applications/{testConsumer.id}/register-applicant-contact-information";
```

I cannot find out why the logic is not working, since similar functions work for me.

**Users.cs**

```
public class Users
{
    public class TestConsumer
    {
        public string id { get; } = "XXXXXXXX";
    }
}
```

**Uri.cs**

```
public class Uri
    {

    private Users.TestConsumer testConsumer;


    public Uri(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
        testConsumer = new Users.TestConsumer();
    }

        public class RegisterUri
        {
                public string RegApplicantInfo1 { get; } = $"/v1/consumer/applications/{testConsumer.id}/register-applicant-contact-information";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You have a constructor `Uri` outside of it's class.... When you declare `testConsumer` (somehow) it's not in the same context as your `Uri` class.

Comment: Your code does not even contain the actual line where the error is being thrown.

Comment: your code appears to be a mess...this will not compile. I assume maybe `private Users.TestConsumer testConsumer;` and `public Uri(...` is supposed to be _within_ the Uri class? And is RegisterUri definitely a class within Uri, or not? And which line of code exactly throws the error? please can you give as a usable example and also identify precisely where the error occurs? Help us to help you...we're not going to be able to guess your problem from a half-baked nonsensical example. If you don't even take a moment to construct your question properly how you can expect us to take time to help?

Comment: @Neijwiert I suppose it´s the interpolated string referring to `testConsumer.id`.

Comment: is this all the code you have in the `Uri.cs`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I suppose you are right. The markup of the code in SO made me overlook that it had that code inserted. I thought it was a 'normal' string.

Comment: Anyway overlooking all that and making some reasonable assumptions about what you meant it to be, the problem is likely to be `{testConsumer.id}`: `testConsumer` here is a property of the `Uri` class, not the `RegisterUri` class...so you don't have access to it in this context. What you _intended_, and therefore what the correct change to make is, however, is not very clear.

Comment: @ADyson sorry about that. I pasted the code quite bad. ofcourse the public uri should be inside the URI class.

Comment: At the time the string is created the `testConsumer` instance is not yet created?

Comment: RegisterUri is a public class in it's own right - it is possible to create an instance of that class without any instances of the Uri class - so trying to use a member of that class is not valid.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop that's also true, as well as the property being a member of the wrong class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1) `testConsumer` is a member of the `Uri` class, not the `RegisterUri` class, so it's not accessible from the context of code running in the `RegisterUri` class.

2) Even if you fix that, you're trying to use `testConsumer` before it has been instantiated. You can't set a hard-coded default value for a property when that value depends on a variable which isn't set until the class is being instantiated.

It's not clear whether you intended `testConsumer` to reside in `RegisterUri`, or you intended `RegApplicantInfo1` to reside in `Uri`, or you had intended `RegisterUri` to inherit from `Uri` (rather than just being an inner class) so that it would be able to access the property from its parent.

So here is *one* way to make the error go away - in this case by using inheritance. `RegisterUri` now inherits from `Uri`, and `testConsumer` is now `protected` so it is accessible to the child class. It seems like it might be the logical approach, but I have no way of knowing if that's the behaviour you actually want (you only described the problem in terms of seeing the error, not in terms of what you were hoping to achieve instead).

```
public class Users
{
    public class TestConsumer
    {
        public string id
        {
            get;
        }

        = "XXXXXXXX";
    }
}


public class Uri
{
    protected Users.TestConsumer testConsumer;
    private Context Context;
    public Uri(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
        testConsumer = new Users.TestConsumer();
    }
}

public class RegisterUri : Uri
{
    public RegisterUri(Context context): base (context)
    {
    }

    public string RegApplicantInfo1
    {
        get
        {
            return $"/v1/consumer/applications/{testConsumer.id}/register-applicant-contact-information";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A6Z41a

Comment: This worked for me, thank you for reading between the lines. But yes, this was what I was trying to recreate. +++++

Answer (score 0):

This code will not even compile I guess... The error is in the second part of the code

It should be something like this:
not sure about this first part, where do you want to set the variable value?

```
public class Users
{
    public class TestConsumer
    {
        public string id { get; }
    }
}


public class Uri
{
   private Users.TestConsumer testConsumer;
   //you are missing this declaration
   private Context context;
   public Uri(Context context)
   {
     this.context = context; <----- here if you try to assign context to Context class, it will give error and ask for a reference
     testConsumer = new Users.TestConsumer();
   }
}
```

Comment: that's true although I think it's just a detail missed out of the code snippet. The new version of the question shows which line generates the error

Comment: He updated the question while I was writing the answer... Will have a look :)

Comment: Yeah, it happens :-). Just thought I'd point it out in case you didn't see

Comment: Sorry about that :)

Comment: Have you tried to add "set" while declaring the property? Because you are giving it a value and there is not set... I have never written a property like this but try...

Comment: @NoWayHandshake that's irrelevant because the original code tries to set a hard-coded initial value for the property at compile-time. But it can't be set at compile-time because it depends on the value of a variable which is only set at run-time when the class is instantiated. A setter is to be used by another piece of code during run-time. Don't confuse it with the setting of a default value.

Comment: @NoWayHandshake anyway the point of my first comment was to encourage you to amend your answer to reflect the new information in the question, so was a bit surprised you haven't done that?